# How to pass multiple variables to a regular (re.search) expression

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I am trying to pass variables using a regular expression (re.search) but I can't seem to successfully read the information into `match.group(1)`, `(2)` etc. using the code below. Could someone take a quick look to see where I'm going wrong?

```
serial = 'abcdeID:11111abcdePR:22222abcde'

id = 11111
pr = 22222

match =  re.search(r'ID:{0}PR:{1}'.format(id, pr), serial)
print("ID value returned = " + match.group(1))
print("PR value returned = " + match.group(2))

#output
#AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do here? Are you just trying to see if the string `ID:11111PR:22222` is a substring of serial? Or do you want to extract the two numbers from the serial (i.e. you don't know what `id` and `pr` are, and want to extract them from `serial`)?

Answer (score 0):

You have no groups `(...)` in your regex, so they're not returned. Add them like that:

```
match =  re.search(r'ID:({0})PR:({1})'.format(id, pr), serial)
```

Comment: Hi mrzasa, thanks for your reply. However I'm still getting the same error: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group' after making the changes you suggested. Seems strange